# Summernote Asp.net MVC HttpRequestValidationException

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I use [Summernote](http://summernote.org/) to enable users to write an HTML email on my website.
The email is submitted if the user submits the Form.
Since the Email is a little more complex with some additional data I use a custom ModelBinder which leads me to my problem.

I try to get the Email text like this

```
argument = request.Form[propertyName] //<-- HttpRequestBase request;
```

The FreeMessageModel looks like this.

```
public class FreeMessageModel : BaseMessageModel
{
    private MvcHtmlString m_FreeMessage;
    private String m_Subject;
    private EmployeeModel m_Employee;

    public MvcHtmlString FreeMessage
    {
        get 
        {
            return m_FreeMessage; 
        }
        set { m_FreeMessage = value; }
    }
    public String Subject
    {
        get { return m_Subject; }
        set { m_Subject = value; }
    }
    public EmployeeModel Employee
    {
        get { return m_Employee; }
        set { m_Employee = value; }
    }

    public String Sender 
    {
        get 
        {
            String from = "someadress");
            return from;
        }
    }

    public FreeMessageModel() 
    {
    }

    public string GetMailBody()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The `request.Form[propertyName]` crashes on `FreeMessage`
with the error Message HttpRequestValidationException.
I am aware that the HTML text is interpreted as possible security issue. My question is how can I get the text so that I can decide if its dangerous myself ?

I read this [Why do I get HttpRequestValidationException submitting user input with raw html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190461/why-do-i-get-httprequestvalidationexception-submitting-user-input-with-raw-html) but this happens after the Modelbinding process.

So the question is How can I get HTML text during ModelBinding without getting 
 a HttpRequestValidationException and without turning off the validation for my whole application

I am using the .Net Framework 4.0

Comment: You can try on your MVC method: `[ValidateInput(false)] ` and in your Model: `[AllowHtml]`

Comment: I get the error in the custom ModelBinder. The ValidateInput(false) seems to have no impact there. But maybe I am missing something else here

Comment: But you forget the second part: `[AllowHtml] public MvcHtmlString FreeMessage`

Comment: With a line break between them xD

Comment: Yeah did that, dind't work either. I have the AllowHtml on my property and the ValidateInput in my modelbinder

Comment: Put [ValidateInput(False)] in your controller method....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621272/allow-user-to-input-html-in-asp-net-mvc-validateinput-or-allowhtml

Comment: I tried that before and now again and it doesn't work. The problem is that the Modelbinder kicks in before the controllers action is called :D. I saw that answer before and it doesn't apply I think.

Comment: @Hackerman I found the error... I had due to Version control a Second webconfig and added the <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" /> into the wrong one. Your answer was completely right ! thx